# Change Kivy button widget attribute by pressing button in another screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

In my app, I have a GameScreen that has a ClueButton1 widget with some text. Pressing that button takes the user to a ClueScreen (using kivy Screen Manager), that has 4 buttons, each being an answer choice. How do I change the background_normal attribute of ClueButton1 on GameScreen when the user presses the correct ClueAnswerButton1 on the ClueScreen?

I've already tried assigning ClueButton1 an id and using that in def check_choice() as GameScreen.cluebutton1id.background_normal = ..., but get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'background_normal'
```

main.py code is here:

```
class GameScreen(Screen):
    ...


class ClueScreen(Screen):
    ...

    def check_choice(self):

        if self.choice0.state == 'down':
            if self.choice0.text == self.correct:
                self.message.text = "[color=006600]Correct! Click back to game and keep" \
                        "playing![/color]"
                self.choice0.background_disabled_down = 'atlas://img/myatlas/green_button5'
                self.choice0.disabled = True
                self.choice1.disabled = True
                self.choice2.disabled = True
                self.choice3.disabled = True
                return
            else:
                self.message.text = "Try again"
                self.choice0.background_disabled_down = 'atlas://img/myatlas/red_button5'
                self.choice0.disabled = True      
    ...
```

And .kv code is here:

```
<GameScreen>:
    GeneralFloatLayout:
    GeneralAnchorLayout:
        GeneralBoxLayout:
            GameGridLayout:
                ClueButton1:
                    text: root.question
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'clue_screen';

<ClueScreen>:
    message: message
    choice0: choice0
    choice1: choice1
    choice2: choice2
    choice3: choice3

    ClueBoxLayout:
        ClueLabel:
            text: "[color=0046C3]" + "Put label Here" + "[/color]"
        ClueMessage:
            id: message
        ClueAnswerButton1:
            id: choice0
            on_press: root.check_choice()
        ClueAnswerButton1:
            id: choice1
            on_press: root.check_choice()
        ClueAnswerButton1:
            id: choice2
            on_press: root.check_choice()
        ClueAnswerButton1:
            id: choice3
            on_press: root.check_choice()
        ClueGridLayout:
            ReturnButton:
                text: 'Back to game'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'game_home'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign the attribute on the class object and not an instance. You can get another screen's instance through `ScreenManager`. Assuming you're running this from the root widget (i.e. `root.check_choice()`):

```
self.manager.get_screen('game_home').cluebutton1id.background_normal = 'path/to/image.png'
```